# How to normalise a line in mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics, histograms

I'm working on creating a line plot from a histogram, as in the following:

```
{g, {binCounts}} = 
  Reap[Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100], 
         {-2,2,0.25}, 
         Function[{bins, counts}, Sow[counts]]]];

{g, ListLinePlot[binCounts]}
```

What I'd like to know is, how can I normalised this line so the area under the curve is 1? (So I can compare the shapes of these histograms independent of the number of counts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use the `"Probability"` hspec in [`Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Histogram.html) (check the docs)
2. Use [`HistogramList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HistogramList.html) to get the data (instead of a plot)

   ```
   {bins, heights} = HistogramList[rr, Automatic, "Probability"]
   ```